# 1D plots from 3D array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D data cube and I am trying to make a plot of the first axis at a specific value of the other two axes. The goal is to make a velocity plot at given coordinates in the sky.

I have tried to create an 1D array from the 3D array by putting in my values for the last two axes. This is what I have tried

```py
achan=50

dchan = 200

lmcdata[:][achan][dchan]  #this array has three axes, vchan, achan, dchan.
```

I am expecting an array of size 120 as there are 120 velocity channels that make up the vchan axis. When trying the code above I keep getting an array of size 655 which is the number of entries for the dchan axis.

Comment: `lmcdata[:][achan][dchan]` works from left to right, firstly `lmcdata[:]` returns `lmcdata` itself so latter slicing is not working as you expected. Maybe you want to try out numpy for high level slicing / indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Python slicing works from left to right. In this case, `lmcdata[:]` is returning the whole `lmcdata` list. So, `lmcdata[:][achan][dchan]` is equivalent to just `lmcdata[achan][dchan]`.

For higher level indexing and slicing tasks like this, I highly recommend the [numpy](https://www.numpy.org) package. You will be able to slice `lmcdata` as expected after turning it into a numpy array: `lmcdata = np.asarray(lmcdata)`.

Comment: With numpy the preferred syntax is `lmcdata[:,achan,dchan]`.